# Angular 2 ngrx/store best practice

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

In my angular 2 applications i start refactoring all the project to ngrx pattern, but i still have some questions in mind :

What my application do i retrieving a list of apps and a list of apps's categories

1- Can i manage state like "selectedCategory" (only one can be selected so its juste a primitive) the old way in this case ? :

**Categories.component.ts**

```
...
...
OnCategorySelect (applicationID : string) {
this.selectedCategory = applicationID 
}
```

Or should i create a selectedCategory reducer for that ?

2 - when passing data from smart component (applicationsListComponent ) to dumb one (categoryComponent) i do it this way with async pipe :

```
**ApplicationsListComponent.ts**

....
....
<app-category [categories]='appCategories | async'></app-category>
```

In this case should i put `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the dumb component to ?

3- In my dumb component (categoryComponent) when i recieve the `categories` from the smart component whith @Input i'am not declaring it as Observable but i'am doing this :

**category.component.ts**

```
 @Input() appCategories: CategoryInfo[];
```

**category.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let app of appCategories'>....</div>
```

So in this case i dont know if i have to declare the data received by @Input from the smart component as Observable.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- For such cases I created separate reducer "selectedCategory". Its implementation is pretty trivial

```
    import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { SELECT_CATEGORY } from '../actions';

    export const selectedCategory: ActionReducer<ICategory> = (state: ICategory, {type, payload}: Action) => {
        switch (type) {
            case SELECT_CATEGORY:
                return payload;

            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

2- Yes. Store in ngrx is immutable. It means that there is no point for Angular in monitoring if some object's property has changed. The only way input data can change is by changing the whole `@Input` object. So `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is fine.

3- No. `@Input` properties should not be Observables. Binding them through `async` pipe (like in your example) is enough. If you pass Observable directly to dump components (without `async`) then Angular change detection will not work as expected. Reference to `Observable` object will stay the same all the time, even if actual data will change. In this case if you want to react to data changes you will need to subscribe (and unsubscribe) to the `Observable` manually, and this will become complete mess.

Answer (score 0):

To add more on @user1614543 's answer

if you wanna detect the change on @Input, which is from an observable source.

Use the following code in your dumb component.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { 
  if (changes.hasOwnProperty('appCategories')) {
     ...
  }
}
```